# VXLAN: how receiver knows that the received packet is VXLAN-encapsulated?

Tags: vlan, protocol-theory, udp, rfc, vxlan

I'm trying to understand how a receiver knows that the received packet is a VXLAN-encapsulated.

Looking at the [VXLAN RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mahalingam-dutt-dcops-vxlan-00#section-5), I can't see anything specific that defines that the packet contains VXLAN header.
I see (parsing the packet from the beginning):

- outer MAC (L2) header
- outer IP (L3) header
- outer UDP (L4) header
- **VXLAN header**
- inner MAC header
- inner ... etc

But I don't see anything specific in the outer UDP header that says that the next header is VXLAN.

What am I missing?

Comment: Linux system uses its default UDP 8972 port number for VXLAN because VXLAN was implemented on it before IANA has assigned a udp port neumber for VXLAN, whereas other systems use IANA assigned VXLAN UDP 4789 port number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The destination UDP port in the outer UDP header is specified in the [VXLAN specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mahalingam-dutt-dcops-vxlan-09#section-5) (Port 4789). This means it is a well-known service. So an UDP packet that arrives on Port 4789 is expected to be a VXLAN packet¹ in the same way that a TCP packet that arrives on Port 80 is expected to be a HTTP packet¹.

The draft you linked to is outdated and is missing this port number (although it mentions that the port number is to be obtained from IANA).

¹) When I talk about VXLAN/HTTP packets I mean of course the respective UDP/TCP packets with VXLAN/HTTP header/protocol inside.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was an outdated RFC, indeed. Note however, that this whole mess with RFC versions and port numbers caused a mess in VXLAN support. Turns out that before port 4789, there was port 8472, and different implementations might still have this old port (such as VMvare ESX).

Comment: Another implementation that uses 8472 is flannel https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel